How do I manage uiState for multiple sections?
I'm currently developing an Android app that displays multiple sections of movie lists. Each section's UI state is managed independently using separate StateFlows in the ViewModel. Here's a simplified version of my current approach:
class MovieViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val _section1State = MutableStateFlow<UiState>(UiState.Loading)
    val section1State: StateFlow<UiState> = _section1State.asStateFlow()

    private val _section2State = MutableStateFlow<UiState>(UiState.Loading)
    val section2State: StateFlow<UiState> = _section2State.asStateFlow()

    // ... more sections ...

    // Functions to update each section
}

This works well for a small number of sections, but I'm concerned about scalability. If the number of sections grows to 100 or more, the amount of code will become unwieldy, and there will be too many management points.
My questions are:

What's the most efficient way to manage multiple section states in a ViewModel when the number of sections can be large and dynamic?

How can I reduce code duplication and simplify state management for numerous similar sections?

Are there any design patterns or architectural approaches that could help in this situation?


I'm looking for a solution that maintains the independence of each section's state while being scalable and manageable. Any insights or best practices would be greatly appreciated.

Your're right, for many states its time consuming way. Probably using List or Map in state would be good enough. Final way depends on your needs. Simpliest solution is to use something like
data class StateReady(val sections: List<SectionUiState>) : UiState

And then generate sections ui base on sections (maybe Recycler?)

The method you suggested is a good method. I also thought about managing it with a List or Map.
Thank you very much!
Still, I wonder if there is another way.

I thought about it some more, but I think it would be difficult to manage the status when managing it as a list.
Because the order of data is unpredictable.
For example, assuming that there are sections 1 and 2, if you process the combined bookmarks, you cannot accurately update the status because you do not know which of sections 1 and 2 will exist in the list.

Selected collection depends on your needs. To be honest your data model should respons to business logic requirements. Im not exactly sure I fully understand the confusion but regardless of the collection you can iterate by all data items and check current state. Your StateFlow(single flow instead of many flows) will inform UI about any change there. UI should be always apropriate to the data state.
